# Как строку преобразовать в байтовый массив JS

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, строки, websocket, byte

пытаюсь понять как с помощью js обычную строку преобразовать в массив байт...
Задача в следующем есть сервер, он передает данные в формате JSON по WebSocket API. [смотреть API](http://iotvega.com/content/ru/soft/server/API%20VEGA-lora%20rev21.pdf).
Я получаю данные, например такую строку "`01639cb8f39d5b1700000000000000000000000000000000`", мне нужно ее по [по вот этому протоколу](http://iotvega.com/content/ru/si/si11/01-%D0%92%D0%95%D0%93%D0%90%20%D0%A1%D0%98-11%20%D0%A0%D0%9F_rev%2019.pdf) прочитать.
Как мне это сделать? не чего похожего в интернете не нашел, что бы c помощью js можно было строку преобразовать в байты, или например из байта выделить биты... и тд...
PS. Если кто нибудь писал уже парсер протоколов iotvega устройств, поделитесь пожалуйста...

Comment: Вообще, для представления двоичной информации в виде текста существует [Base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), но в Вашем случае придётся изучать, как работает упомянутый Вами протокол.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указанная строка ('*01639cb8f39d5b1700000000000000000000000000000000*') представляет собой набор байтов пакета в шестнадцатеричном виде.

Это означает, что каждые два символа кодируют один байт.

Перевод из шестнадцатеричного вида в десятичное число можно осуществить с помощью функции [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) передав вторым значением основание 16, например

```
parseInt('01',16) // 1
parseInt('63',16) // 99
```

> В полях, состоящих из нескольких байт, используется порядок
>   следования little endian

Это означает, что нужно поменять порядок байт на обратный.

То есть для строки "1234" → "12" "34" → "34" "12" → "3412"

И только потом применять `parseInt`: `parseInt('3412', 16) // 13330`

---

Для лучшего понимания можно разобрать вручную указанную строку.

1. нужно разделить ее на байты: `["01","63","9c","b8","f3","9d","5b","17","00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00"]`
2. Первый байт указывает тип пакета, в данном случае `01` → `1`
3. Далее следуя [описанию протокола](http://iotvega.com/content/ru/si/si11/01-%D0%92%D0%95%D0%93%D0%90%20%D0%A1%D0%98-11%20%D0%A0%D0%9F_rev%2019.pdf) для типа пакета 1 идут следующие поля:

   1. Заряд батареи, % *(1 байт)*: `63` → `99`
   2. Значения основных настроек (битовое поле) *(1 байт)* - разбор этого поля указан в документации: `9c` → `156`
   3. Время снятия показаний, передаваемых в данном пакете (unixtime
      UTC) *(4 байта)*: `"b8","f3","9d","5b"` → `"5b", "9d", "f3", "b8"` → `1537078200` *(количество секунд)* → `1537078200*1000` *(количество миллисекунд)* → `new Date(1537078200*1000)` → `2018-09-16T06:10:00.000Z`

И т.д.

С остальными типами пакетов – по аналогии.

Answer (score 0):

Может поможет

```js
function string2Bin (str) {
  const result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result.push(str.charCodeAt(i).toString(2))
  }
  return result
}

function bin2String (array) {
  let result = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(array[i], 2))
  }
  return result;
}

const bin = string2Bin('01639cb8f39d5b1700000000000000000000000000000000')
console.log(bin2String(bin))
console.log(bin)
```